# Creating a class with generic types at runtime

Tags: java, generics

I have the following interface defined:

```
public interface AllImplementMe<X, Y> {
    public Y doSomething(X param);
}
```

Now I wish to define a factory method which needs to construct sub classes for above at runtime.

```
public static <X,Y> AllImplementMe<X, Y> createInstance(String xClassName, String yClassName) { ... }
```

How do I actually code the above method? I've been looking at reflection API but unable to figure it out? It is assumed that all sub classes have a default constructor.

**Edit1**

I just want to add some clarification regarding the intent of the above code. The above is just a part of generic system which will allow new implementing sub classes to be added at runtime and be executed based on externally defined configuration. So in reality the factory method will be called based on this configuration and construct appropriate child object which will then be asked to execute their methods. This is conceptually similar to the Adnroid's AsyncTask http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html with the problem that I need to construct implementing child class objects in a generic fashion. For most part the core code that will call these children is not concerned with their param types.

Comment: Are you looking for an anonymous class?

Comment: And what is the role of the `X param` in the `doSomething` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following factory method instead:

```
public static <X, Y> AllImplementMe<X, Y> createInstance(Class<X> xClass, Class<Y> yClass)
```

Then you can use things like `xClass.newInstance()` to create an instance of `X`.  (I haven't written the exact code since I don't know exactly what you want to do with `X` and `Y`.)

Comment: When he(/she) says sub-class, isn't it means some class implementing `AllImplementMe` ?

Comment: Yes this is one way to do it as it puts the burden of supplying these type params to the caller who is expected to know about them anyway. Still a generic solution using the original signature would still be preferred!

Comment: The way I suggested is the standard way of supplying these classes, and it's less error-prone (and the IDE will support you better if you refactor) if you use `MyClass.class` instead of a string like `"com.myclass.MyClass"`.  The caller must already know the classes in order to use the return type.  You could use `Class.forName(xClassName)`, but then you'd have to cast it or use `Class.asSubclass`, which is kinda icky, especially if the class names they specified as the parameters don't actually match X and Y.

Comment: I've accepted your answer, this was the correct way to do it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Everything is much simpler. You even do not need these parameters `String xClassName, String yClassName`.

Consider you have some implementation of your interface:

```
public class SomeImplementation<A,B> implements AllImplementMe<A,B> {
   @Override
   public B doSomething(A param) {
       //      ... blablabla ...
   }
}
```

Then your static factory method will be just:

```
public static <A, B> AllImplementMe<A, B> createInstance() {
    return new SomeImplementation<A,B>();
}
```

Comment: The Factory method itself being sourced to the sub class is more of a workaround. The implementation of the factory method must be generic so that all child classed do not have to simply implement a factory method and return their instance from it. I prefer not to use inheritance when composition can more than answer for it!

Comment: Ou, dear, you can not use class's type variables in static method declaration. Are you sure, that you understand generics theory well?